# When TableViewCell selected, destination viewcontroller refreshing 2 times

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2

When I click on tableview cell I want to go detail of table view. But first it comes dummy screen, after that my data is loading . I don't want to see dummy screen. How can i avoid dummy screen?

```
import UIKit
class ProductDetailVC: UIViewController {   
@IBOutlet weak var backBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var CampaignImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var TitleLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var SubTitleLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var DefinitionLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var DescriptionTxt: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var rewardImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var FisiCek: UIButton!


var receivedAltResim: String = ""
var receivedDetailDesc: String = ""
var recievedTitleofDetail: String = ""
var recievedSubtitleofDetail: String = ""
var recirevedReward: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let url = NSURL(string: receivedAltResim) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            CampaignImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    TitleLbl.text = recievedTitleofDetail
    SubTitleLbl.text = recievedSubtitleofDetail
    DescriptionTxt.text = receivedDetailDesc    }
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}   
}
```

this is where I select the cell and transfering data with segue.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let campaigns = self.campaigns[indexPath.row] as Campaigns

    altResim = campaigns.AltResimUrl
    detailDesc = campaigns.Description
    reward = campaigns.Bonus
    titleofDetail = campaigns.Title
    subtitleofDetail = campaigns.Subtitle

    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    /*  if segue.identifier == containerSegueName {
     containerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ContainerVC
     }
     else*/
    if segue.identifier == "showDetailSegue" {

        let detailVC : ProductDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ProductDetailVC

        detailVC.receivedAltResim = altResim
        detailVC.receivedDetailDesc = detailDesc
        detailVC.recirevedReward = reward
        detailVC.recievedTitleofDetail = titleofDetail
        detailVC.recievedSubtitleofDetail = subtitleofDetail
    }

}
```

Comment: so you are displaying `ProductDetailVC` on tableview's row's click? and from where are you getting data to fill UI of `ProductDetailVC` ? If it is from server then it definitely take time to fetch. If this is the case then you should display loader or `activity indicator view` till you  successfully get data from server

Comment: Can you show the code for selecting a cell in the table view?

Comment: I edit my question with the code for selecting cell

Comment: I fixed the issue with segue.

Comment: NSData(contentsOfURL: url) is blocking your UI thread.
You should load that image on a background thread, then update the UI when it's complete.